# Data is not being inserted into sql serve ce in c#

Tags: c#, insert, sql-server-ce

![program is running, but no data is being inserted into database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJG8b.jpg)

I am trying to insert data through this form into sql server ce database file LocalDB.sdf. All is working well, but no data is being inserted into the database. I cant find any clue of what went wrong. Is there somebody who can help. Thanks in advance.

![Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn5rB.jpg)

Comment: Since external links don't live forever we don't like them here. Post your relevant code and describe your problem (what happens vs expected) in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have included the database file as content in your project, and it gets copied to your bin/debug directory when you debug, due to use of DataDirectory in your connection string. Best practice is to not include the database file in your project, or use a full path in your connection string while debugging.

Comment: Thank you so much ErikEj. It worked. But if I run this program in a different machine it will not work. ConnectionString would has to be changed. Is there any solution!!

Comment: Yes, you can use DataDirectory in the deployed app.config, and set its value as I describe here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/10/sql-server-compact-4-desktop-app-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SqlCommand instead of adapter like below:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.Connection = con;
  cmd.CommandText = "Insert into ..."
  con.Open();
  int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  MessageBox.Show("Rows affected: " + rowsAffected.ToString());
}
```

If number of rows affected will be equal to 1 it means record was inserted